# How do you insert a date in a table?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have this table but I'm not sure what is the format for entering dates

```
insert into Works (ClientID, CCode, BranchNo, EquipNo, HireDate)
select 001, 101, 01, 24500, '23-JAN-13' from dual union
select 002, 102, 01, 23200, '12-SEP-12' from dual union
select 003, 103, 01, 11500, '15-DEC-14' from dual union
select 004, 104, 01, 76830, '16-MAR-16' from dual union
select 005, 105, 01, 23760, '08-JUN-15' from dual
```

This doesn't work, it just gives me this error:

> ORA-00904: "HIREDATE": invalid identifier

New error: https://m.imgur.com/gallery/LkrLsol

Comment: check `hireDate` format in your table.

Comment: Well, in spite of all the comments properley formatting your data string, the converting to an actual DATE data type, none of that has anything to do with your actual reported error message.  The message says HIREDATE is an invalid identifier.  In other words your table does not have a column named HIREDATE.    I would also reiterate that useing 2-digit years is utter foolishness.  I spent most of 1998 and 1999 busting my butt to fix Y2k issues for my then employer.  And now we are raising up a new generation who refuses to learn the lesson.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using valid date literals:

```
insert into Works (ClientID, CCode, BranchNo, EquipNo, HireDate)
select 001, 101, 01, 24500, date '2013-01-23' from dual union
select 002, 102, 01, 23200, date '2012-09-12' from dual union
select 003, 103, 01, 11500, date '2014-12-15' from dual union
select 004, 104, 01, 76830, date '2016-03-16' from dual union
select 005, 105, 01, 23760, date '2015-06-08' from dual
```

You could also use Oracle's `TO_DATE` function:

```
TO_DATE('23-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY')
```

Comment: is that the only possible format? like can i do DD-MM-YYYY?
Also thanks for helping

Comment: Now I get this error with DD-MM-YYYY format, also your format (YYYY-MM-DD) doesnt work.
`ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`

Comment: @FiveNine Use `TO_DATE('23-JAN-13', 'DD-MON-YY')` if you really must stick with your current non ANSI date literals.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Playing the devil's advocate, if the OP expects each record to always have a unique client ID, then using union vs. union all might have slightly better performance.

Answer (score 3):

`'23-JAN-13'` is not a date, it is a string. Avoid using two digit year `'YY'`. That's the reason **Y2K** bug started.

To insert `DATE` values:

Use `TO_DATE` with appropriate format mask:

```
TO_DATE('09-05-2020', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```

Or,

`ANSI` Date literal, it uses fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`:

```
DATE '2020-05-09'
```

Comment: I tried the latter and I got this error even tho the dates and month value was under 12.
`ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month`

Comment: @FiveNine Show me what you are doing, copy paste your session.

Comment: I couldnt copy-paste the code here, it keeps messing up so i took a screenshot and put it on imgur
https://i.imgur.com/JmW5moR.png

Comment: Damn my bad, sorry. Thanks for helping me out!